# Updating and exporting XY positions in UTM and WGS84 to spreadsheet using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, wgs84, utm

On a daily basis I'm editing the geographic positions of various points of a shapefile (corner_XY.shp) by dragging them on my map. When this editing task is done I'm updating the points coordinates in their attribute table column by column by right clicking on the column and calculate geometry.

I have 4 columns: Latitude - Longitude - X_UTM - Y_UTM
Latitude/longitude in WGS84 (format= DD MM SS,SSS) and X_UTM - Y_UTM in WGS84 UTM Zone 15 N.

I'm then exporting the attribute table with the updated fields (Latitude - Longitude - X_UTM - Y_UTM) to an excel spreadsheet to share it with my team.

Exemple of output:

```
X_UTM        Y_UTM      Latitude            Longitude
596697.989  2276072.78  20° 33' 58.529" N   91° 9' 16.333" W
599675.251  2123364.47  20° 32' 28.838" N   91° 12' 18.624" W
575317.464  2263171.52  20° 23' 51.409" N   91° 6' 35.489" W
....        .....       ......              ......
```

My project is a projected one in WGS84 UTM Zone 15 N and my shapefile containing the points that I'm moving on a daily basis (corner_XY.shp) is in WGS84 not projected. I'm using ArcGis 10.1.

GOAL: I'm trying to replicate those tasks using the model builder in order to automatically update and export the new position of my points in WGS84 and UTM to an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you please supply a visual of what you are trying to accomplish? Also, it would be useful to have a clear description of what the final product would look like--I am not sure if you want a shapefile or excel table with the updated coords.

Comment: I've clarified my demand. My output is an excel table with the updated coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've done your edits, you could run a model with the following tools:

1.[Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Copy_Features/001700000035000000/). Copy your shapefile to a feature class. This will allow you to use the Alter Field tool in step 3. And it will leave your input intact so you don't have to be afraid of modifying it, and won't bother deleting the fields added in the steps below.

2.[Add Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Geometry_Attributes/001700000191000000/). Check the POINT_X_Y_Z_M Geometry Properties. This will add the latitude and longitude fields if your input's coordinate system is WGS 1984.

3.[Alter Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Alter_Field/001700000198000000/). Use this tool twice to rename the POINT_X and POINT_Y fields created in the previous step to something like LONG and LAT. This tool is new to 10.2.1, I see you have added the ArcGIS 10.1 tag, if you can't upgrade you should use [Add Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Field/001700000047000000/) and [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) to transfer the field values to another field.

4.Add [Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Geometry_Attributes/001700000191000000/) again, Check POINT_X_Y_Z_M in Geometry Properties AND specify WGS 1984 UTM Zone 15N in the coordinate system parameter.

The Geometry Attributes tool overwrites field values if the fields it creates already exist, that's why you should change the name of the fields in step 2.

5.[Table To Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_To_Excel/001200000054000000/) to export your rows to an Excel file.

Comment: The Add Geometry Attributes tool seems to be unavailable for ArcGis 10.1. A workaround for the step 2 that you proposed is add XY and use Convert Coordinate Notation to get DD MM SS. However I'm stuck at step 4. Maybe reprojecting in utm and add XY. I'm considering an update to 10.2 it seems to have some useful tools.

Comment: Yes if you can't migrate to 10.2.1, you need additional steps (reprojecting etc). I was not sure how new Add Geometry Attributes was. Indeed there a bunch of nice tools in 10.2.1, migrate if you can, no uninstallation nor reauthorization needed.